# Process doesn't work due simulation

Tags: vhdl

I wrote this code to understand process in vhdl but strangely I saw the simulation that doesn't work properly
my code :

```
entity test is
    port(
        i1 : in std_logic;
        i2 : in std_logic;
        r : out std_logic
    );
end test;

architecture Behavioral of test is
signal g : std_logic;
begin
    process(i1)
        begin
        if i1 = '1' then 
            g <= '1';
        else 
            g <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
    process(i2)
    begin
        if i2 = '1' and g = '0' then
            r <= '1';
        else
            r <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

and this is my result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTU1Y.jpg)

when i process i1 so g should be 1 in the first period so r should be 0 but r is 1 after i2 is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using `g` in the second process but it is not in the process sensitivity list.

```
process(i2,g)
begin
    if i2 = '1' and g = '0' then
...
```